# Link home directory to filestore

Tags: linux, home, google-cloud

I have two GCE instance (RHEL8) and a common file store mounted as `/filestore` on both instance.

How can we link the existing `/home` to `/filestore/home` as shared storage for users home directory.

Note: currently we have user's home directory available on `/home`

Comment: Here are pretty thorough instructions: https://ostechnix.com/move-home-directory-to-new-partition-in-linux/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a bind mount

`mount -o bind /filestore/home /home`

You can add this to your `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Does this the first mount point (/filestore/home) inaccessible?

Comment: @JeremyBoden no